# Adding list data to a test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, wrapper-class

```
 global class AcquirersPJRestWrapper {
    
    global String codOffer;
    global String channel;
    global List<Technology> technologies;
}

global class Technology{
    global String deviceType;
    global Integer quantity;
}
```

//Class Test

```
@istest(SeeAllData=True)
global class testee {

@isTest(SeeAllData=True)
static void test() {
    
    AcquirersPJRest.AcquirersPJRestWrapper proposta = new AcquirersPJRest.AcquirersPJRestWrapper();
    proposta.codOffer = 'OFFER-01';
    proposta.channel = '350';
    
    AcquirersPJRest.Technology tec = new AcquirersPJRest.Technology();
    tec.quantity = 5;
    tec.deviceType = 'AAA';
    proposta.technologies.add(tec);      
    
    System.debug('proposta'+proposta);
      
    }
}
```

//Error
//System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

How do i add tec to the "proposta" object?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that `proposta.technologies` is null. It's declared as a list, but your test never initializes it. Your code right now basically evaluates to `null.add(tec);`

`null.<something>` gives you a Null Pointer Exception.

Adding `proposta.technologies = new List<AquirersPJRest.Technology>();` prior to your `proposta.technologies.add(tec);` line should sort you out. There's a natural place in your code that you should add this line to, but your list only *needs* to be initialized before you try to `.add()` to it.

Also, you should not be using `seeAllData=true`. It is necessary in only a few, very rare situations, and I don't think this is one of them. You should also not use the `global` class modifier unless you know that it's needed.

Comment: Thank you. It worked after doing what you recommended.